# How can I mint new token from ink smart contract calling pallet-balances function?

Tags: pallet, smart-contract

How can I mint a new native token (not a custom token) from the ink smart contract calling one of the functions from pallet-balances pallet?

Comment: Generally native tokens are only minted on genesis or through consensus, but I suppose you could do it with a [chain extension](https://use.ink/macros-attributes/chain-extension/).